# Passing index expression with filter() to database

Tags: indexing, dplyr, rlang

I have PostgreSQL table *table* with lot of rows.
In order to make queries faster and to ensure UTC time zone, it indexed by `timezone('utc'::text, t.closed_at)::date`

for getting data I use following code, but it's slow

```
    t  <- tbl(wcon, 'table') 

today     <- as.character( as_date(Sys.time()- hours(1)))
# weekdays compare
wks_n <- 5
prev_weeks <- Sys.Date()-wks_n*7

lh_f <- t %>% 
  filter(closed_at >= prev_weeks,
         closed_at <= today) %>% 
  collect()
```

How I can pass values to this index expression with `filter()` ?

As a faster workaround I use creating query like this

```
my_query <- paste0("select * from table t ", 
               "where timezone('utc'::text, t.closed_at)::date ",
               "between ", prev_weeks, " and ", today)
```

Comment: dbplyr which enables dplyr just transforms R code to SQL and then runs this on the DB - probably not every aspect of a powerfull tool like postgres has been translated (your expert postgres knowledge should be far ahead of dbplyr/dplyr)... so I am afraid your "workarround" is the proper solution for the case... anyhow you could write your SQL as a view with no filter just casting the date and then reference the view to filter it in dbplyr/dplyr (not sure about the performance though)

Comment: Thank you @DPH !
I had the same idea about creating a view and use it with filter() instead of original table